# Fill object with result from db

Tags: php, oop, pdo

Lets say we have this class:

```
class Cup {
    public $color;
    public $material;

    public function getMyCupById($id){
        //prepare statement
        $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM cups WHER cup_id=?');
        $query->bindValue(1,$id);
        $query->execute();

        $cup = $pages->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        // The "problem" is from here
        $this->color = $cup->color;
        $this->material = $cup->material;
        // To here
    }
}
```

So, is this the right way to "fill" an object from DB or there is more elegant way to do this?

At the end, the execution code will be:

```
$cup = new Cup;

//other lines of code

$cup->getMyCupById($id);
```

Comment: i don't get it... what is exactly the problem??? and post any error messages

Comment: So it's working but you don't know if it's the best way to do it? btw the method isn't returning anything, which is of course not required but it would make more sense.

Comment: what you are doing works, obviously no error.. not sure what you are expecting outside of validation that what you are doing is okay. the only answers that can be given are opinionated, in my opinion. keep on keepin' on.

Comment: There are no error messages. I was just wondering if this is the right way to "update" an object. Because it's first called with $cup = new Cup; when $cup is object with default values, and at some point, it's "updated" with a method.

And yes, I was just asking for opinions and ideas, because I'm not sure if this is the right way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of including the database interaction in your Cup class, you could just define it as:

```
class Cup {
    public $color;
    public $material;
}
```

And have a separate data access class to handle the database interaction.

```
class CupDataAccess {
    private $db;

    public function __construct(PDO $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getMyCupById($id) {
        $sql = 'SELECT color, material FROM cups WHERE cup_id=?'
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindValue(1, $id);
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchObject('Cup');
        // Using fetchObject this way will automatically associate column
        // names from the fetched row with corresponding property names of
        // the specified class.            
    }    
}
```

So you could create Cups with

```
$cupDataAccess = new CupDataAccess($pdo);
$cup = $cupDataAccess->getMyCupById(1);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if I just replace $cup = $pages->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); with return $pages->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); And then --> $cup = new Cup;
$cup = $cup->getMyCupById($id);

Comment: That would give you a `$cup` that would not be a `Cup`, but rather a `stdClass` with property names corresponding to the columns in your cups table. That seems fine if that's all you need. I just assumed your `Cup` class probably had other methods/properties that you had not included in the question.

Comment: This is indeed the better aproach. A dataobject should not be responsible for gettin itself out of the database. You should design your classes so they only do whatever they need to do. An easy example should be a car, a car can drive, brake, accelerate, etc.
But a car can't get itself out of a garage. Let the car be a car and let the garage figure out which car the driver  wants

Comment: I would say the driver figures out which car [s]he wants, and the garage provides access to cars. Of course this is only true unless you extend the Car class to create Transformers or Knight Rider, which obviously complicates things.